# Should I use returns in multiline Scala methods?

Tags: scala, coding-style, return

Perhaps this is just my background in more imperative programming, but I like having return statements in my code.

I understand that in Scala, returns are not necessary in many methods, because whatever the last computed value is is returned by default. I understand that this makes perfect sense for a "one-liner", e.g.

```
def square(x) = x * x
```

I also understand the definitive case for using explicit returns (when you have several branches your code could take, and you want to break out of the method for different branches, e.g. if an error occurs). But what about multiline functions? Wouldn't it be more readable and make more sense if there was an explicit return, e.g.

```
def average(x: List[Int]) : Float = {
  var sum = 0
  x.foreach(sum += _)
  return sum / x.length.toFloat
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def average(x: List[Int]) : Float = 
  x.foldLeft(0)(_ + _) / x.length.toFloat
```

UPDATE: While I was aiming to show how an iterative code can be made into a functional expression, @soc rightly commented that an even shorter version is `x.sum / x.length.toFloat`

I usually find that in Scala I have less need to "return in the middle". Furthermore, a large function is broken into smaller expressions that are clearer to reason. So instead of

```
var x = ...
if (some condition) x = ...
else x = ...
```

I would write
  if (some condition) ...
  else ....

Similar thing happens using match expressions. And you can always have helper nested classes.

Once you are comfortable with many forms of expressions that evaluate to a result (e.g., 'if') without a return statement, then having one in your methods looks out of place.

At one place of work we had a rule of not having 'return' in the middle of a method since it is easy for a reader of your code to miss it. If 'return' is only at the last line, what's the point of having it at all?

Comment: Thanks for the `foldLeft`, I hadn't seen that yet, and in my Scala noobishness I tried to reinvent the wheel

Comment: `def average(x: Int*): Double = x.sum / x.length.toDouble` should work too.

Answer (score 10):

The `return` doesn't tell you anything extra, so I find it actually clutters my understanding of what goes on.  Of *course* it returns; there are no other statements!

And it's also a good idea to get away from the habit of using `return` because it's really unclear where you are returning *to* when you're using heavily functional code:

```
def manyFutures = xs.map(x => Futures.future { if (x<5) return Nil else x :: Nil })
```

Where should the return leave execution?  Outside of `manyFutures`?  Just the inner block?

So although you can use explicit returns (at least if you annotate the return type explicitly), I suggest that you try to get used to the last-statement-is-the-return-value custom instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your sense that the version with the `return` is more readable is probably a sign that you are still thinking *imperatively* rather than *declaratively*.  Try to think of your function from the perspective of what it *is* (i.e. how it is defined), rather than what it *does* (i.e. how it is computed).

Let's look at your `average` example, and pretend that the standard library doesn't have the features that make an elegant one-liner possible.  Now in English, we would say that the average of a list of numbers is the sum of the numbers in the list divided by its length.

```
def average(xs: List[Int]): Float = {
   var sum = 0
   xs.foreach(sum += _)
   sum / xs.length.toFloat
}
```

This description is fairly close to the English version, ignoring the first two lines of the function.  We can factor out the `sum` function to get a more declarative description:

```
def average(xs: List[Int]): Float = {
   def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = // ...
   sum(xs) / xs.length.toFloat
}
```

In the declarative definition, a `return` statement reads quite unnaturally because it explicitly puts the focus on *doing* something.

Answer (score 2):

I don't miss the return-statement at the end of a method because it is unnecessary. Furthermore, in Scala each method does return a value - even methods which should not return something. Instead of `void` there is the type `Unit` which is returned:

```
def x { println("hello") }
```

can be written as:

```
def x { println("hello"); return Unit }
```

But `println` returns already the type Unit - thus when you explicitly want to use a return-statement you have to use it in methods which return `Unit`, too. Otherwise you do not have continuous identical build-on code.

But in Scala there is the possibility to break your code in a lot of small methods:

```
def x(...): ReturnType = {
  def func1 = ... // use funcX
  def func2 = ... // use funcX
  def func3 = ... // use funcX
  funcX
}
```

An explicitly used return-statement does not help to understand the code better.

Also Scala has a powerful core library which allows you to solve many problems with less code:

```
def average(x: List[Int]): Float = x.sum.toFloat / x.length
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not use `return`, I think it somehow goes against the elegant concept that in Scala everything is an expression that evaluates to something.

Like your `average` method: it's just an expression that evaluates to `Float`, no need to return anything to make that work.